# XSS vulnerability

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, xss

I got the below error when I testing my mobile application. How can i resolve this XSS error?

The value of the q request parameter is copied into the HTML document as plain text between tags. The payload `2906f<script>alert(1)</script>b08ffac3085` was submitted in the q parameter. This input was echoed unmodified in the application's response.

This proof-of-concept attack demonstrates that it is possible to inject arbitrary JavaScript into the application's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encode it for HTML before you put it in the HTML document.

With JavaScript (since that is the only language you've mentioned), that generally means using `createTextNode` instead of `innerHTML`.